# Best way to add text to a logo image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve something like the picture below for my logo but only the black rectangle would be an image, I'd like the text to be real text.
I tried the code below (see also jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ueZ2H/ which seems to be working) but not sure if this is a clean and efficient manner to achieve this?
Many thanks

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <div class="name">Dave Black</div>
        <div class="address">Address in Paris</div>
        <div class="job">Job</div>
    </div>
</div
```

CSS:

```
/***********/
/*! Reset  */
/***********/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

}
Html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/************/
/*! Header  */
/************/
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #000;
    height: 95px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#logo .name {
    padding-left:90px;
    color: red;
}
#logo .address {
    padding-left:90px;
    color: green;
}
#logo .job {
    padding-left:90px;
    color: purple;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You might consider looking at how Stack Exchange displays user info on questions/answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself some CSS, and make adding other fields easier, by including the padding in the container, not on the `name`, etc. lines.  The background image will stay in place.

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #000;
    height: 95px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 90px;
}

#logo .name {
    color: red;
}

#logo .address {
    color: green;
}

#logo .job {
    color: purple;
}
```

Also, unless you plan on using `name`, `address` and `job` classes elsewhere, there's no reason to qualify them here:

```
.name {
    color: red;
}

.address {
    color: green;
}

.job {
    color: purple;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ueZ2H/1/

Answer (score 1):

I trimmed some of the fat from the css

```
 Html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background: #fff;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

 #header {
width: 100%;
height: 280px;
}

 #logo {
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
height: 95px;
font-size: 20px;
background: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg")   no-repeat;
padding-left:90px;
}

#logo .name {
 color: red;
}

#logo .address {
color: green;
}

#logo .job {
color: purple;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KpjYS/2/

Answer (score 0):

This works, I would change `font-size` and `vertical-align` to make it pop. Text will always render better than image-text in browsers.